# How do I pass ruby arguments to pry-rescue?

Tags: ruby, pry

I have a Ruby script that I run like this:

```
$ ruby -I my_libs my_script.rb
```

I want to run it with [pry-rescue](http://bitly.com/pry-rescue) but I can't figure how to pass arguments to Ruby (the interpreter, not the script). The [pry-rescue](http://bitly.com/pry-rescue) documentation implies that you just replace `ruby` with `rescue` to use it, so I thought this would work:

```
$ rescue -I my_libs my_script.rb
```

but it doesn't.

**Is there a way to pass command-line arguments to `ruby` via `rescue` ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a work-around, you can pass arguments via the `RUBYOPT` environment variable. So here is one way to pass `ruby` arguments via `rescue`:

```
$ RUBYOPT='-I my_libs' rescue my_script.rb
```

Note however, as per `man ruby`, that `RUBYOPT` can contain only a subset of the available ruby options, so this is not a complete solution to the problem.